# How to Sort total liquidity by top liquidity available?

Tags: pancakeswap, liquidity-provider, decentralized-exchange, binance-smart-chain

Hi I am making a DEX and I am stuck with a problem, I want to Sort total liquidity by top liquidity available for a token paired with BNB or native token. I am using 0x API but there is nothing to do with liquidity, Is there any API that gives liquidy or liquidity provider info?

for e.g.

I want to liquidity of BNB and this address [0x21381e026ad6d8266244f2a583b35f9e4413fa2a](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/formation-fi/)

Comment: Could you bring some precision on what you mean by "Liquidity", like what are you trying to quantify exactly ? The term is rather broad (LP token total supply ? BNB balance ? Number of LP ? Uni V3 ?)

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth LP token total supply and Number of LP or maybe we can also check if the liquidity of Token is locked.

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Total supply with respect to value-based tokens such as BNB, USDT, USDC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to get liquidity of `0x21381e026ad6d8266244f2a583b35f9e4413fa2a` in pancakeswap. But this token in Ethereum. You cannot do that.

Secondly, let's get liquidity on bnb-cake liquidity for example.

1. Go to PancakeSwap [Factory V2](https://bscscan.com/address/0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73#readContract)
2. Call getPair function with addresses of cake and bnb (you can't enter bnb's address, you have to enter wbnb).
3. And the function returns: 0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0
4. Go to that address from in [bscscan](https://bscscan.com/address/0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0#readContract).
5. You can get all reserves in the bottom.
6. If you want to get total supply of LP token, you can go to token tracker from [here](https://bscscan.com/token/0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0).